# Simulink misses data points in a from-workspace block for discrete simulation

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulation running at 50 Hz, and some data that comes in at 10 Hz. I have extra 'in-between' points with dummy data at the following 50 Hz time points, and interpolation set to off. This should in theory ensure that between 10 Hz time steps, the dummy data is being held and only at the 10 Hz steps is the actual data present. For example, my data vector would be

```
[0.0 0.8 0.1 0.12 0.2 0.22 0.3 0.32 0.4 0.42 0.5 0.52 ...
  -1  -1   1   -1   2   -1   3   -1   4   -1   5   -1 ...]
```

However, with a scope attached directly from the 'from-workspace' block, simulink is returning this:

```
[0.0 0.8 0.1 0.12 0.2 0.22 0.3 0.32 0.34 0.4 0.42 0.5 0.52...
  -1  -1  -1   -1   2   -1   3    3   -1   4   -1   5    5...]
```

where some values are skipped and others are repeated in a consistent pattern. Is there something with simulinks time-step algorithms that would cause this?

Edit: A solution I ended up finding was to offset the entire time vector by 1/100th of a second so that the sim was taking data between points rather than on points, and that seemed to fix it. Not ideal, but functional.

Comment: Have you specified the output sampling period for the block that takes the data from the workspace? As an alternative, what about using timeseries instead of a simple vector?

Comment: I have tried sampling at 50 Hz and 10 Hz, and the result is the same. Attaching a scope directly and logging to the workspace confirms that the values are missing. The solution I ended up finding was to offset the entire time vector by 1/100th of a second so that the sim was taking data between points rather than on points, and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: That solution makes it sound like the issue was due to numerical precision, incrementally adding the timestep could mean the "current" time is not exactly aligned with your input data timestamps within machine tolerance

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Annoying more than anything, and certainly not ideal.